# Why have questions been removed from my account?

Tags: discussion, support

I have an account on English Language and Usage and I asked two question from this account those has been removed and I can not see them in asked question column so I want to know what are the reason for removing those questions.

Comment: One more vote, and the _estation_ question will be undeleted. I hope that happens – even if the question doesn't get reopened, there are two very good answers to that question that deserve to be in our archives.

Comment: @J.R. yupp that's why i was surprised, as i dont get any alert or information why they have deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of your questions, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71686/difference-in-english and [Difference in starting pronunciations of "station" and "sun"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/difference-in-starting-pronunciations-of-station-and-sun) were deleted after having been closed. The first case was a question which was very broad, and your edits didn't make it less so. In the second case, your question didn't make much sense to other users because "station" doesn't start with an "e" sound. You later changed your question in comments, but did not actually update it in the five days since closing.

Deletion can happen to questions which have been closed (except usually for duplicate questions, which are more often merged). Like closing, deletion is done via a voting process.

Comment: Too bad about the _estation_ question being closed & deleted. I was initially very confused by that question, but once tchrist & Mitch gave their answers, I found the overall result very enlightening and informative. I even used that question as an anecdote in campaigning for the ability to rescind close votes on [SE meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/136291#136291) (something I don't expect we'll ever see, but that's another issue). BTW, that question was only closed yesterday; it got most of its close votes within a few hours of it being asked, but held at 4 for several days.